# d3 bisector not working with array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects

```
var s = [{"4":0},{"5":0},{"8":0},{"14":0}];
```

and a `d3.bisector()`:

```
var bd = d3.bisector(function(d,y){ return y;}).left;
```

When calling it like this

```
bd(s,5)
```

it outputs `0`. The bisector fails if I use "key" of the object instead of a value in the accessor function. Can someone shed some light as to why is this happening?

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882631/d3-what-is-a-bisector)

Comment: Not really, The problem is that the bisector fails if you're using object "key" as the returning value. Otherwise, I know it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two adjustments to make it work:

1. To use the keys for comparision, you have to explicitly access them. Given your array of objects this could be done by `d3.keys(d)[0]`, thereby comparing the first and only key. In case you want to numerically compare the keys, this will be `+d3.keys(d)[0]`.
2. Because you specified your callback as `function(d,y) {}`, i.e. taking two arguments, the function is expected to be a comparator returning boolean values. The easiest way in your case would probalby be to provide a one-argument callback being an accessor to the objects keys.

The following code should work as expected

```js
s = [{"4":0},{"5":0},{"8":0},{"14":0}];

var bd = d3.bisector(function(d) {
  return +d3.keys(d)[0];
}).left;

console.log(bd(s, 5));   // 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```