# d3.js: bisector always returns zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

http://jsfiddle.net/rdpt5e30/1/

```
const data = [
  {'year': 2005, 'value': 771900},
  {'year': 2006, 'value': 771500},
  {'year': 2007, 'value': 770500},
  {'year': 2008, 'value': 770400},
  {'year': 2009, 'value': 771000},
  {'year': 2010, 'value': 772400},
  {'year': 2011, 'value': 774100},
  {'year': 2012, 'value': 776700},
  {'year': 2013, 'value': 777100},
  {'year': 2014, 'value': 779200},
  {'year': 2015, 'value': 782300}
];

const bisect = d3.bisector(function(t: any) { return t.year; }).left;

console.log(bisect(data, 4));
```

Not matter which position I give it it always returns index 0.. it's literally the same example I've seen [countless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882631/d3-what-is-a-bisector) times, yet it doesn't seems to be working for me for some reason..

Any ideas?

Comment: It returns 0 because 0 is less than all years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that we are not supposed to pass it an index, but a value that matches the selector function, so in case of my example 2010 for example.